# RESTEasy service for producing xml and returning array/list of JAXB objects giving empty collection

Tags: xml, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying out RESTEasy webservices. I have written simple service to return List of JAXB Customer objects and expecting the returned xml to be collection of Customer tags under Collection tag. But what I am getting is `<Collection/>`, means an empty collection.

My code is :

**Customer Service**

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {

List<Customer> customersList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

public CustomerService() {
    customersList.add(new Customer(.....)); //Creating Customers using parametarized Cunstructor
    customersList.add(new Customer(.....));
    customersList.add(new Customer(.....));
    customersList.add(new Customer(.....));
    customersList.add(new Customer(.....));
}

@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/xml/list")  
public List<Customer> getAllCustomersList(){
    return customersList; //nonEmpty list of Customers
}
}
```

**Customer (JAXB Object)**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
private String customerId;
private String name;
private String address;
private int age;
public Customer() { }

public Customer(String customerId, String name, String address, int age) {
    super();
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.age = age;
}

@XmlAttribute
public String getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

@XmlElement
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlElement
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@XmlElement
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

    }
```

I am able to get single Customer with this Service, which works just fine :

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@Path("/xml/{id}")  
public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String customerId){
    for(Customer customer: customersList){
        if(customerId.equals(customer.getCustomerId()))
            return customer;
    }
    return null;

    }
```

I have made the service singleton so the list is not empty, that for sure. Even I have debugged the code to confirm that the list is not empty.
I tried with the array also and same is happening.

Here is the thing, I am reading from:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Built_in_JAXB_providers.html#JAXB_Collections

I am using

- WebSphere Application Server 8.0
- RESTEasy 2.2.3GA

Comment: What does `<Collection/>` have to do with a serialized `Customer`? And why do you return `customersList`? What is this?

Comment: @Tichodroma Please see the link from the question. I am trying to return a list of Customer objects : List<Customer>,  Which should result in something like    <collection><customer>...</customer><customer>...</customer> <collection>

Comment: And where does this list of `Customer`s come from? Are you sure it is not empty?

Comment: See I have updated the code. customersList is the field in CustomerService. Service is singleton. Also as I mentioned in the question, the list is not empty, i have checked.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to make the serialization work with your Customer POJO by making the following changes:

- Moved the `@XmlElement` annotations to the fields
- Added `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation to tell JAXB to bind by fields and ignore getters/setters.

**Method:**

```
@GET
@Path("/customers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Customer> getCustomer()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    customers.add(new Customer("1", "customer1", "some address 1", 20));
    customers.add(new Customer("2", "customer2", "some address 2", 45));
    customers.add(new Customer("3", "customer3", "some address 3", 36));

    return customers;
}
```

**Customer POJO:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer 
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String customerId;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    private String address;

    @XmlElement
    private int age;

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public Customer(String customerId, String name, String address, int age)
    {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() 
    {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) 
    {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getAge() 
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) 
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
    <customer customerId="1">
        <name>customer1</name>
        <address>some address 1</address>
        <age>20</age>
    </customer>
    <customer customerId="2">
        <name>customer2</name>
        <address>some address 2</address>
        <age>45</age>
    </customer>
    <customer customerId="3">
        <name>customer3</name>
        <address>some address 3</address>
        <age>36</age>
    </customer>
</collection>
```

### What if you want to change the name of the wrapping element?

If you don't like the xml list being returned wrapped in a `collection` element and want to change the name you can add the `@Wrapped` annotation to your resource method like so:

```
@GET
@Path("/customers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Wrapped(element = "customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomer()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    customers.add(new Customer("1", "customer1", "some address 1", 20));
    customers.add(new Customer("2", "customer2", "some address 2", 45));
    customers.add(new Customer("3", "customer3", "some address 3", 36));

    return customers;
}
```

This wraps the list of customers in a `customers` element instead of `collection`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer customerId="1">
        <name>customer1</name>
        <address>some address 1</address>
        <age>20</age>
    </customer>
    <customer customerId="2">
        <name>customer2</name>
        <address>some address 2</address>
        <age>45</age>
    </customer>
    <customer customerId="3">
        <name>customer3</name>
        <address>some address 3</address>
        <age>36</age>
    </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: No luck with this too. Still giving empty <collection/>. I am returning same list with content type application/json from different method, and I can see the complete expected list in result. I think that means something might be wrong with JAXB Customer class.

Comment: Have you tried annotating the properties with @XmlElement and not the getters?